# Convert phone line to Ethernet signal

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have DSL which comes into my house through the phone line. I then have a modem that it plugs into which handles connecting to the remote ISP. The modem has then several eithernet ports that can be used for the network.

I would like to know if I can get rid of the modem and try to convert the phone line signal into an Ethernet signal that I can use to plug into my [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) equipped router. I'm pretty sure the router can handle the basic configuration needed to talk to the ISP's server itself.

So is this possible - or do I just have to stick with the router sitting behind that cheap modem?

Comment: So you want a device .. that will modulate and demodulate the phone signal into something an Ethernet device can listen to? Some sort of device that modulates/demodulates ... like a mo/dem device?

Comment: So I got a downvote for asking a dumb question?

Comment: Presumably so, since that on-hover shows this tool-tip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)"

Comment: You have to have the modem. You may not have to have THAT modem, but to connect to DSL you are going to have to have a DSL modem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You need a modem. What you actually have is a device which combines the modem with a router.

If you log into this device and disable LAN DHCP, plug your DDWRT router into one of the LAN ports, and then all your devices into the DDWRT, you will have achieved your goal of using the DDWRT for LAN administration and configuration.

Your question about the modem indicates that you should read up on the subject a little.

Comment: Not sure if DD-WRT supports it, but in all of my setups I use PPPoE so that my router gets full control rather than the (probably crappy) software on the Modem that has a DHCP client limit of 4 or something similar.